# automatically send an email when a file gets generated

Tags: python, bash, scripting

I am trying to write a python script that automatically sends an email when a specific file is generated. I think i have the code for sending the email, but im not sure how to monitor a directory looking for a specific file.

a high level example is:

from within directory foo/
when file baz is populated do sendEmail()

Comment: On which operating system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os.path
if os.path.exists(file_path) and os.path.isfile(fname):
   send_email()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import smtplib,time
```

## function which monitors when your_file.txt was generated

```
def search_file():
    try:
        my_file=open('your_file.txt','r')
        content=my_file.read()
        my_file.close()
        return content
    except:
        print "Waiting..."
        time.sleep(20)
        search_log()
```

## server and port

```
mail=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
```

## identify to the server ESMTP

```
mail.ehlo()
```

## start TLS mode = encrypt smtp for login

```
mail.starttls()
mail.login('user','pwd')



mail.sendmail('originator','receiver',search_log())

mail.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, which is independent of the path/directory in which the file is located:

```
import os
if 'your_file.txt' in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
#do something
```